# Pdfbox ExtractImage saves same image for each page

Tags: java, pdfbox

**Pdfbox(1.7.1)** *ExtractImage* class extract image with a glitch. My target pdf file has 136 pages and only one image at page 1(Cover image). The code saves that image 136 times.

The problem is getResources from each page. Each time different resources was obtained (# is different for each page). But each resources supply an image with different # but same key value.

I temporarily solve this by comparing key value from previous image.

But is it a pdfbox fault? Or some fault in my compilation of pdfbox 1.7.1?